# Compile error when trying to compile boost and openssl (When using Websocket++ or CPPRestSDK)

Tags: c++, boost, g++, cpprest-sdk

I am currently trying to get a working tls websocket client running in C++ (<strike>which is a pain in the ass</strike>) and I have tried CPP Rest SDK as well as Websocket++. Both spit out a bunch of compile errors (see below). When I tried compiling it using Websocket++ without tls, it compiles so the error clearly is related to SSL.

I tried different OpenSSL versions (1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0), different C++ versions (11, 14 and even 17), and I just can't get it to compile.

I googled and none of the solutions worked. I am on Ubuntu 16 and the build command I am using looks like this:

```
g++ source/* -o test.out -Iinclude/ -std=c++14 -L/lib64 -lcurl -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -l pthread
```

Here are some of the errors:

```
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp: In constructor ‘boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init()’:
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/openssl_init.ipp:43:23: error: expected id-expression before ‘(’ token
 mutexes_.resize(::CRYPTO_num_locks());

/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/engine.ipp:221:9: error: ‘SSL_R_SHORT_READ’ was not declared in this scope
     ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, 0, SSL_R_SHORT_READ),
```

And here is the basic source code:

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>
#include <iostream>

// pull out the type of messages sent by our config
typedef websocketpp::config::asio_tls_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;

typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_tls_client> client;

using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

void on_close(client* c, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
    c->get_alog().write(websocketpp::log::alevel::app, "Connection Closed");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    client c;

    std::string uri = "wss://gateway.discord.gg/";

    if (argc == 2) {
        uri = argv[1];
    }

    try {
        // set logging policy if needed
        c.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::frame_header);
        c.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::frame_payload);
        //c.set_error_channels(websocketpp::log::elevel::none);

        // Initialize ASIO
        c.init_asio();

        // Register our handlers
        c.set_open_handler(bind(&on_open,&c,::_1));
        c.set_fail_handler(bind(&on_fail,&c,::_1));
        c.set_message_handler(bind(&on_message,&c,::_1,::_2));
        c.set_close_handler(bind(&on_close,&c,::_1));

        // Create a connection to the given URI and queue it for connection once
        // the event loop starts
        websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;
        client::connection_ptr con = c.get_connection(uri, ec);
        c.connect(con);

        // Start the ASIO io_service run loop
        c.run();
    } catch (const std::exception & e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (websocketpp::lib::error_code e) {
        std::cout << e.message() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "other exception" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the errors directly.  External sites are not reliable.  Links rot.

Comment: Also, "none of the solutions worked" - which solutions? How did they not work? ... and can we have a [mcve] please.

Comment: @MartinBonner Most of the solutions where just "use this or that version of boost/OpenSSL". Also, I added some of the errors to the question (pasting all of them there would be way too much for a question).

Comment: @MartinBonner Also, I just added the example I am trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

This was a long time ago but in case it helps, adding `-lcrypto -lssl` in the g++ cmd arguments solved the problem for me.